# 3-rd party component for file transferring via sockets - Java

Tags: java, ftp, network-programming

I study computer-science and right now I am in a middle of Networking course.
I need to develop a simple FTP program (client + server).
The server listens to port X and waits to connection request. Every client has it's own thread. 
The server send the client the current list of files it has.
The client ask for file and in that point I need to open new socket for the file transferring.
When half of the file was sent the client need to take a decision if he wants the rest of the file - at that time the server waits for the client's decision.

Although it seems a little problem and although I did chat programs based on TCP and UDP on the previous courses  I got stuck.

I search for 3-rd party component that simplify the file transferring.

Thank You,
Oz

Comment: "I search for 3-rd party component that simplify the file transferring."  Cool, let us know how that goes.  If you should form any *questions* in the mean time, feel free to pop by and ask them.

Answer (score 0):

[Common IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) has a lot of nice utilities to deal with files and sockets.